# Is initializing a superglobal by PHP codes a right thing?

Tags: php, superglobals

Here is my code:

```
    $order_newest = $order_votes = $order_featured = $order_frequent = '';

    if ( isset($_GET['o']) || isset($_COOKIE['qanda_questions_order']) ) {

        // To read from the cookie
        if ( !isset($_GET['o']) ) {
            $_GET['o'] = $_COOKIE['qanda_questions_order'];
        } else {
            setcookie("qanda_questions_order", $_GET['o'], 2147483647);
        }

        switch ($_GET['o']) {
            case 'newest':
                $order_newest = 'order_active';
                break;
            case 'votes':
                $order_votes = 'order_active';
                break;
            case 'featured':
                $order_featured = 'order_active';
                break;  
            case 'frequent':
                $order_frequent = 'order_active';
                break;                                          
            default:
                $order_newest = 'order_active';
                break;
        }

    } else {
        $order_newest = 'order_active';
    }
```

As you see, I've initialized a supergobal on this line:

```
$_GET['o'] = $_COOKIE['qanda_questions_order'];
```

Is doing that a right thing? Or only should supergobals be used as passed parameters in the URL *(get method)* ?

Also can I write this logic more better? *(seems Unprofessional to me a little bit)*

Comment: Why _are_ you using the superglobal instead of just another variable?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Because I've used the superglobal in the *`switch`*

Comment: It's perfectly fine.  It just keeps you from having to do `$o = $_GET['o'];` and then using `$o`.

Comment: Instead assign it to a variable. Use shorthand instead `$variable = $_GET['o'] ?? $_COOKIE['qanda_questions_order']` and use `$variable` for switch. Although no problems, you can use this way, no body going to offend you for such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opinions vary, but in my opinion it is really bad practice to modify superglobals that are pre-filled by PHP. I always treat them as "read-only" variables (with the exception of `$_SESSION`) myself, even though there's nothing stopping you from writing to them. I would personally use a variable for this:

```
if (isset($_GET['o']) || isset($_COOKIE['qanda_questions_order'])) {
    $order = isset($_GET['o']) ? $_GET['o'] : $_COOKIE['qanda_questions_order'];
    setcookie("qanda_questions_order", $order, 2147483647);

    switch ($order) {
       // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with modifying the superglobal, but you don't need to do so, and you don't need to create another variable either.

```
if ( isset($_GET['o']) ) {
    setcookie("qanda_questions_order", $_GET['o'], 2147483647);
}

switch ($_GET['o'] ?? $_COOKIE['qanda_questions_order'] ?? '') { // ... cases
```